# Upload files not working, whats wrong with this code?

Tags: php, upload

This is the PHP code used for the upload:

```
$upload = "uploads/";
$upload = $upload . basename($_FILES['bgimage']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bgimage']['tmp_name'], $upload)) {

    echo "The file has been uploaded successfully.";

} else { echo "Error"; }
```

When I test the script, it says "The file has been uploaded successfully." but when I check the FTP server, it hasn't really...

Also, if you need to know, here's the HTML codes:

Form tag:

```
<form name="profilestyle" action="account.php?action=profiletheme" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Input tag:

```
<input type="file" name="bgimage" />
```

Extra Information:
Yes, I remembered the CHMod the uploads directory

Answer (score 1):

Odd, the code looks fine as far as I can see.

Can you use `file_exists()` to check whether the file exists, but maybe is not visible to your FTP user?

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bgimage']['tmp_name'], $upload)) {

echo "The file '$upload' has been uploaded successfully.";
if (file_exists($upload)) echo "And it exists! It is ".filesize($upload)." bytes big.";
 else echo "But it doesn't exist.";

} else { echo "Error"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check `$_FILES['bgimage']['error']` to make sure it is equal to `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` and is not an error code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following test code

```
$upload = "uploads/";
$upload = $upload . basename($_FILES['bgimage']['name']);

sprintf('<pre>Debug: moving file from %s to %s</pre>',
  $_FILES['bgimage']['tmp_name'],
  $upload
);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bgimage']['tmp_name'], $upload)) {
  echo "The file has been uploaded successfully.";
  sprintf('<pre>Debug: realpath=%s, filesize=%d</pre>',
    realpath($upload),
    filesize($upload)
  );
}
else {
  echo "Error";
}
```

and esp. keep an eye on the [realpath](http://docs.php.net/realpath)=xyz output.